# how to prevent ng-click from firing for a short interval

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<button type="button" 
    class="btn btn-primary" 
    ng-click="$parent.paginationInstance.nextPage()" 
    ng-disabled="($parent.dataList && $parent.dataList.length < $parent.paginationInstance.pageSize)">
        Next
</button>
```

I'm new to angular, 
above is what I want to do:
we will not be able to click Next page button (it will be disabled as grey) when there is not enough data in current page.
(suppose there is 35 records, and 10 per page, then we can't click next in page 4.)
everything looks good except:
when I click NEXT in a very quick way,it will turn to page 5 or 6 without disabling, of course they are empty page.
so may I know if there is a way to limit this?

Comment: Consider using the [ng-show directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) to only reveal the button when there is data available for the next page.

Comment: Using `$parent` to access data and functions is a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell), an indication of a deeper implementation problem. What is going on that you need to use `$parent`? Maybe there is a better way to do things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could disable it right after click

```
button.ngDisabled = true
```

And then add into the ready state function

```
button.ngDisabled = false
```